# java 8 getting string value for current date with offset

Tags: java, datetime

I want to the get the current date in this format "2017-09-07T11:55:32+00:00"
but not overly familar with how to do it in Java 8.. have tried

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    String todaysDateTime = now.format(formatter);
```

gives me an error

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: 
OffsetSeconds
```

anyone know i how i do this?

Comment: what is wrong with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

Comment: gives me the value "2017-11-08T14:31:31.783" .. no offset

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` is defined as a date/time with no time zone or offset. Thus, you can't convert it into one (without supplying the offset, that is). Please use one of the appropriate types.

Comment: Is the required offset `+00:00` (zero offset) always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OffsetDateTime odt = now.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(1, 0));
System.out.println(odt);
```

The toString of all time variants already give the corresponding ISO format.

```
2017-11-08T15:31:04.115+01:00
```

However instead of +00:00 it will give Z. Also the milliseconds are given. So either use this standard, or make your own pattern.

Your format would be:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");
```

where the small `x` (instead of `X`) does no "Z" substitution, and xxx is needed for the colon `:`.

---

So the resulting string can be gotten as (thanks @OleV.V.):

```
OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.‌​ofPattern("yyyy-MM-d‌​d'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"))
```

---

***The other direction:***

`LocalDateTime` wraps a long, a milliseconds since - count. It no longer holds the offset as in `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = fmt.parse(inputString);
Instant instant = odt.toInstant(); // Bare bone UTC time.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(odt.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")); // UTC too.
```

*(This is a bit more complicated than I thought.)*

Comment: thanks for this.... so that format you suggest above gives me the same error... 

    LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.now();
        
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-
    dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");
        
    String dateString = ld.format(fmt);

Comment: You still need to format an `OffsetDateTime` (or a `ZonedDateTime`) with that formatter, not a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"))`.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for explaining (my answer), and I will shamelessly add your one-liner to my answer.

Comment: follow up question... how do i go in the opposite direction.... i.e. parse a string in iso format and get my local date/time time adjusted?... i.e.. given 2017-11-06T11:55:32+09:00  to get 2017-11-06T02:55:32+00:00

Comment: Added the other direction. The API is a bit overwhelming, but the javadocs will after a (offset/local date) time add meaning to all. Good success.

Comment: thanks Joop, but that reverse was gives me "2017-11-06T11:55:32"


DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");
OffsetDateTime offsetDateStartTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-11-06T11:55:32+09:00", formatter);

LocalDateTime dateStartTime = LocalDateTime.from(offsetDateStartTime);

Comment: Corrected. So I have my misconceptions too, I already avoided the pitfall of `OffsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime`). Thanks that I could correct it.

Comment: thanks Joop...i need to get reading some good tutorials on this Java 8 apis!